# Confusion about orderby in the mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Below is the mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `is_product_info` ORDER BY (select distinct product_id from is_product_images where is_product_images.product_id = is_product_info.id) asc
```

I am not getting how the order by works with subquery here.

I came across such queries having order by with subquery in the wordpress plugin. This is new to me so I am asking if someone else knows this. Below is such example:

```
SELECT wp22_posts.* 
  FROM wp22_posts 
  LEFT 
  JOIN wp22_term_relationships 
    ON wp22_posts.ID = wp22_term_relationships.object_id
 WHERE 1=1 
   AND wp22_posts.ID IN(260,412,413,414,415,469,474,483
                       ,485,487,488,515,516,563,568‌​,569
                       ,584,592,593,596‌​,599,601,604,610
                       ,612‌​,672,675,678,681,690‌​,860,861,862,863)
 GROUP 
    BY wp22_posts.ID 
 ORDER 
    BY (SELECT distinct meta_value from wp22_postmeta where'meta_key' LIKE 'price') ASC 
 LIMIT 0, 10
```

Is there anybody who describe this query?

Comment: That's because it's gibberish

Comment: I came across such queries having order by with subquery in the wordpress plugin. This is new to me so I am asking if someone else knows this.

Below is such example:

SELECT wp22_posts.* FROM wp22_posts LEFT JOIN wp22_term_relationships ON (wp22_posts.ID = wp22_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND (wp22_posts.ID in (260,412,413,414,415,469,474,483,485,487,488,515,516,563,568,569,584,592,593,596,599,601,604,610,612,672,675,678,681,690,860,861,862,863)) GROUP BY wp22_posts.ID ORDER BY (SELECT distinct  meta_value from wp22_postmeta where'meta_key' LIKE 'price') ASC LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: However, the sample WordPress query is very poor and was constructed by someone who doesn't really understand what they're doing

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the ORDER BY clause does nothing at all (other than potentially stop the query from working).